# My ascx control inside a container update panel does a full refresh when one of the controls inside it is clicked

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ascx

My ascx control inside a container update panel does a full page refresh when one of the controls inside it is clicked.
Has anyone faced this behavior before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the control is inside the update panel then this is how it should work.  When an event is fired inside the update control it is supposed to refresh.  Now if you had an update panel inside the control and the button being clicked were in the update panel and the whole control was refreshing then this would be odd behavior!

Try putting an additional update panel in the control and then manually set the events for what is to cause which update panel to actually update.  This will give you more control!

Comment: As an aside I suggest taking a brief look at jQuery and learning how to use its very powerful AJAX concepts.  Do your best to stay away from the update panel and all things magic in the ASP.NET AJAX libraries!